# Using Tensorflow JS in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, tensorflow.js

I have been trying to load a pre-trained model to use to make predictions in a chrome extension but I am getting the error "**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tf.loadLayersModel is not a function**
". I trained the model using python and saved it with

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "./models")
```

In the chrome extension, my popup.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
    <script src="tensorflow.js"></script>
</html>
```

My tensorflow.js file is

```
async function loadModel(){
    var json = chrome.runtime.getURL('./models/model.json')
    chrome.storage.local.set({'model': json})
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('models/model.json')
}
learnLinear();
```

and my manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My Project",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Tensorflow project",
  "permissions": ["activeTab" ,"declarativeContent" ,"storage", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "mod1/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest; object-src 'self'",
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I am not sure why it is not recognising the loadLayersModel function. Please can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

replace your content_security_policy with this line in manifest.json file:

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

Comment: Could you clarify what this does and why it solves the issue? The link you've provided as "DOC" is not actually documentation, it's just the latest version of Tensorflow. Did you mean to point to another page?

Comment: I edited my previous comment.  StackOverflow put additional characters somehow. Basically, you need to copy the whole string from tfjs example of "content_security_policy" from https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples/blob/master/chrome-extension/dist/manifest.json  and add the URL of the latest tfjs script inside that string.   You are missing "unsafe-eval" in your "content_security_policy".  Let me know.